# Serializer failing to add extra data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In django rest framework i am trying to add an object in a ModelSerializer with some custom functionality.

I want one of the fields to be set to `self.request.user` and i have the following view:

```
class GigSubmitView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (ProviderRW,)
    serializer_class = serializers.GigSubmitSerializer
    queryset = models.Gig.objects

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(provider=self.request.user)
```

However that doesn't seem to be the correct answer. What should i do instead?

Comment: Can you add serializer code also?

Comment: Do you want pass single object to serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to override the perform create method to access request object in the serializer.

You have 2 options:

1. use serializer.context['request'] to access request object in serializer

request object is inserted by default in all generic views.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context

2. you can use the current user default method to set the current user

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault